# How to record a video and save it from webcam?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script to view and save webcam footage with Python. However, it allows me to view the video but when its saved it saves a blank output.avi file and I dont know why can someone help;

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
rows = (int(vc.get(3)))
cols = (int(vc.get(4)))
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (rows, cols), False)
        
if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False


while rval:
    
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    out.write(frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)

    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        vc.release()
        out.release()
        break



cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I use cv2.VideoCapture(1) as its footage from the 2nd Webcam I require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not setting isColor to false.

Your script worked for me with `out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (rows, cols))`